# Spring Framework Basics: .xml not found?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, xml-parsing

I'm quite new to Spring, trying to create an MQTT client service. I have simple autocreated project and want to try the xml coniguration of the Paho Client as suggested in https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html .

DemoApplication.java:

```
@Configuration  
@ImportResource( { "mqtt.xml" } )  
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

mqtt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="clientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory">
    <property name="userName" value="${mqtt.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${mqtt.password}"/>
</bean>

<int-mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter id="mqttInbound"
    client-id=""
    url="${mqtt.url}"
    topics="sometopic"
    client-factory="clientFactory"
    channel="output"/>
</beans>
```

I have an autogenerated (`gradlew build`) .classpath file. However, no matter where I try to store the mqtt.xml file, typing `gradle build` always fails at the test, claiming:

> IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/mqtt.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/mqtt.xml]

...

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/mqtt.xml]

.classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/main" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/main" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8/"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/default"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save mqtt.xml file inside Java classpath i.e. src/main/resources to resolve the above issue.

Comment: This was my first guess. Unfortunatly doesn't work. I'll attach the .classpath, maybe there's something wrong there.

Comment: Sure please attach the same

Comment: I did attach it to the original post